# python: how to pass a context to a function

Tags: python

What is the correct way to pass a context (with no specific type) to a function? 
There are multiple methods, each accepting a context in their signature. Each function knows what variable it should look into context (in the example below f1 knows it should look for "a"). I can't figure out how I can define context and set a value to one of it's properties.

I am writing this with C background in mind, so it might look a little bit awkward in python world, and any suggestion how to redo this whole thing is also accepted. In C, context should be defined completely for all the variables it might set. In python since it's dynamic I am under the impression that we should not need a type for the context variable, but then I am not sure without defining context how I can set context.a.

A simplified example of what I am trying to do is shown below:

```
def f1(context):
    a = context.a
    print "a: " + a

def f2(context):
    b = context.b
    print "b: " + b

context1.a = "testing1"
f1(context1)

context2.b = "testing2"
f2(context2)
```

Comment: It's not obvious what you're trying to do. Python's variables aren't typed, so you can just initialize a variable and pass it to a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define an "empty" class, and dynamically add variables to an instance of that class in your code:

```
#!python3

class Context:
    pass

def f1(context):
    a = context.a
    print("a:", a)

def f2(context):
    b = context.b
    print("b:", b)

c = Context()
c.a = 1
c.b = "alfalfa"

f1(c)
f2(c)
```

Comment: That was smart! Is there a dummy class in python I can use instead of defining my own Context class?

Comment: @apadana: No. You cannot mutate direct instances of `object`.

Answer (score 1):

Python is a dynamic language, therefore you can pass any arbitrary type as any argument and it is up to the code within the function to do the right thing.

["Duck typing" on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing)

Comment: Can you explain it a bit with an example, so that some beginner like me can understand?